# Import Shapefile to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, import, postgis, shapefile

I am trying to import a shapefile to Postgres using the following:

```
shp2pgsql c:\location\water_areas.shp water > water.sql
```

I am receiving the following message:

```
c:\location\water_areas.shp: shape (.shp) or index file (.shx) can not be opened, will just import attribute data.
```

Unfortunately I need more than just attribute data. I need the geometry column. Please help. Why won't it open the shapefile for the conversion.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16760/import-shapefile-to-postgres

Answer (score 3):

Without any extra information, there's no way to answer your question. The error message is indicating the app is not finding one or more of the file components. Try running the app inside the 'location' directory with a relative path and see if that changes.